# Нахождение производной (символьное дифференцирование) - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, парсер, visual-c++, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите написать программу для нахождения производной по введенной строке. Найденную производную вычислять не надо. 
Например: (2x^3 + cos4x)' = 6x^2 - sin4x; (lnx + 8 - √x)' = 1/x - 1/(2*√x) и т. п. по таблице производных.

Есть парсер, строящий дерево и вычисляющий математические операции. Но вместо вычисления математических операций, результаты парсинга нужно преобразовать в производную. Как это сделать не совсем ясно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

struct Expression {
    Expression(std::string token) : token(token) {};
    Expression(std::string token, Expression a) : token(token) {
        this->args.push_back(a);
    }
    Expression(std::string token, Expression a, Expression b) : token(token) {
        this->args.push_back(a);
        this->args.push_back(b);
    };

    std::string token;
    std::vector<Expression> args;
};

class Parser {
public:
    explicit Parser(const char* input) : input(input) {}
    Expression parse();
private:
    std::string parse_token();
    Expression parse_simple_expression();
    Expression parse_binary_expression(int min_priority);

    const char* input;
};

std::string Parser::parse_token() {
    while (std::isspace(*input)) ++input;

    if (std::isdigit(*input)) {
        std::string number;
        while (std::isdigit(*input) || *input == '.') number.push_back(*input++);
        return number;
    }

    static const std::string tokens[] =
    { "+", "-", "**", "*", "/", "mod", "abs", "sin", "cos", "(", ")" };
    for (auto& t : tokens) {
        if (std::strncmp(input, t.c_str(), t.size()) == 0) {
            input += t.size();
            return t;
        }
    }

    return "";
}

Expression Parser::parse_simple_expression() {
    auto token = parse_token();
    if (token.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input");

    if (token == "(") {
        auto result = parse();
        if (parse_token() != ")") throw std::runtime_error("Expected ')'");
        return result;
    }

    if (std::isdigit(token[0]))
        return Expression(token);

    return Expression(token, parse_simple_expression());
}

int get_priority(const std::string& binary_op) {
    if (binary_op == "+") return 1;
    if (binary_op == "-") return 1;
    if (binary_op == "*") return 2;
    if (binary_op == "/") return 2;
    if (binary_op == "mod") return 2;
    if (binary_op == "**") return 3;
    return 0;
}

Expression Parser::parse_binary_expression(int min_priority) {
    auto left_expr = parse_simple_expression();

    for (;;) {
        auto op = parse_token();
        auto priority = get_priority(op);
        if (priority <= min_priority) {
            input -= op.size();
            return left_expr;
        }

        auto right_expr = parse_binary_expression(priority);
        left_expr = Expression(op, left_expr, right_expr);
    }
}

Expression Parser::parse() {
    return parse_binary_expression(0);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double eval(const Expression& e) {
    switch (e.args.size()) {
    case 2: {
        auto a = eval(e.args[0]);
        auto b = eval(e.args[1]);
        if (e.token == "+") return a + b;
        if (e.token == "-") return a - b;
        if (e.token == "*") return a * b;
        if (e.token == "/") return a / b;
        if (e.token == "**") return pow(a, b);
        if (e.token == "mod") return (int)a % (int)b;
        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown binary operator");
    }

    case 1: {
        auto a = eval(e.args[0]);
        if (e.token == "+") return +a;
        if (e.token == "-") return -a;
        if (e.token == "abs") return abs(a);
        if (e.token == "sin") return sin(a);
        if (e.token == "cos") return cos(a);
        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown unary operator");
    }

    case 0:
        return strtod(e.token.c_str(), nullptr);
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown expression type");
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

int errors;

void test(const char* input, double expected) {
    try {
        Parser p(input);
        auto result = eval(p.parse());
        if (result == expected) return;
        std::cout << input << " = " << expected << " : error, got " << result << '\n';
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << input << " : exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    ++errors;
}

int main() {
    test("0", 0);
    test("1", 1);
    test("9", 9);
    test("10", 10);
    test("+1", 1);
    test("-1", -1);
    test("(1)", 1);
    test("(-1)", -1);
    test("abs(-1)", 1);
    test("1+20", 21);
    test("1 + 20", 21);
    test("1+20+300", 321);
    test("1+20+300+4000", 4321);
    test("-1+20", 19);
    test("--1+20", 21);
    test("---1+20", 19);
    test("(1+20)", 21);
    test("-2*3", -6);
    test("2*-3", -6);
    test("1++2", 3);
    test("1+10*2", 21);
    test("10*2+1", 21);
    test("(1+20)*2", 42);
    test("2*(1+20)", 42);
    test("(1+2)*(3+4)", 21);
    test("2*3+4*5", 26);
    test("100+2*10+3", 123);
    test("2**3", 8);
    test("2**3*5+2", 42);
    test("5*2**3+2", 42);
    test("2+5*2**3", 42);
    test("1+2**3*10", 81);
    test("2**3+2*10", 28);
    test("5 * 4 + 3 * 2 + 1", 27);
    std::cout << "Done with " << errors << " errors.\n";
}
```

Comment: Есть ведь готовые формулы для вычисления производных от разных операций - умножения, деления, сложения (очевидно), от функций и т.д. Так что делаете функцию, которая принимает на вход Expression  и выбирает одну из формул (смотря какой оператор попался в Expression'е). Функция получится рекурсивная. Потом вызываете ее для корня дерева.

Comment: @HalyBlackCat , я по началу так и делал, но потом так вышло, что они начали противоречить друг другу. Как я ни пытался, всегда приходил в тупик.